# inputting sentence and turning it into string

Tags: c++, cin

```
int main(void)

{
char x[20];
cout << "enter a C string:";
cin >> x;
cout << x << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I know that cin will skip all the leading white spaces when reading data of the required type until it sees the next white space. So if I type "abc school", only "abc" is read into x. What should I do if I want the whole sentence to be read into x?

Answer (score 2):

Use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) in std library. The website is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

best solution is to use getline, and change data type of x to string:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)

{
string x;

cout << "enter a C string:";
getline(cin,x);

cout << x << endl;
return 0;
}
```